# Setting video height/width to actual size

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

When a new **MediaElement** is made and inserted into a **Grid**, it is auto-sized to fit the entire Grid size. How can you adjust the proportions of the MediaElement to mimic the video's original size ?

```
Grid gDim = new Grid();

MediaElement plr = new MediaElement();
plr.Source = new Uri(my_string); // web link to video file
plr.Play();
plr.Width = plr.NaturalVideoWidth ;
plr.Height = plr.NaturalVideoHeight ;
plr.AreTransportControlsEnabled = true;

gDim.Children.Add(plr);
```

Setting the NaturalVideoWidth/Height makes the MediaElement go invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try my advice for this case(using `Stretch` property)?

```
<MediaElement Stretch="None"/>
```